# Adding key, adjusting node shape and magnifying a tikz diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-trees

I wish to reproduce the diagram shown in the picture below:
[image]
Below is my MWE which I developed by imitating the solution provided at [Modifying a decision tree terminal nodes using `tikz`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561638/modifying-a-decision-tree-terminal-nodes-using-tikz).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
    patterns,positioning,
    shadows,shapes,
    trees}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{0081FF}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}[
                ->,>=stealth',
                level/.style={sibling distance = 3cm/#1, level distance = 10mm},  
                basic/.style = {draw, drop shadow, font=\sffamily\small, text=white,
                    rounded corners=2pt, thin}, % <---
                split/.style = {basic, fill=blue},    % <---
                leaf/.style = {basic, fill=#1},      % <---
                leaf/.default = red
                ]
                \node [split,rectangle, draw, fill=black,minimum size=.8cm] {}
                child{ node [split,circle,minimum size=.8cm] {}
                    child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=.4cm] {}}
                    child{ node [split, circle, minimum size=.8cm] {}
                        child{ node [split,circle,minimum size=.8cm] {} 
                            child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=.4cm] {}}
                            child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=.4cm] {}}}
                        child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=.4cm] {}}
                        }
                    }
                %
                child{ node [split,circle,minimum size=.8cm] {}
                    child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=.4cm] {}}
                    child{ node [split,circle,minimum size=.8cm] {}
                        child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=.4cm] {}}
                        child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=.4cm] {}}
                         }
                    };
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Tree Structure}
        \label{fig:decision-tree}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here are the challenges with my MWE:

1. I have failed to add the key of my decision tree as shown in the picture I wish to reproduce. The key is supposed to be a black rectangle for a root, a blue circle for an internal node and a small red circle for a terminal node.  **NB: I wish to have this key to my tree structure diagram take the same layout as the one in the picture that I wish to reproduce.**
2. I have also failed to create a rectangular black node in my MWE. I have tried to specify the shape of the node (the root of my decision tree) and to adjust its size using the command `\node [split,rectangle, draw, fill=black,minimum size=.8cm]` as in [How to change the size of nodes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13587/how-to-change-the-size-of-nodes) but the node remains a **square**.
3. I have also failed to magnify the diagram in my MWE, the tikz diagram is too **huddled** at the moment.

### Progress made so far:

Thanks to @[Raffaele Santoro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/24644/raffaele-santoro) problems 2 and 3 above have been solved. What is left now is problem 1. I wish to have a key to my tree diagram appear as one in the picture that I wish to reproduce. The key added by @[Raffaele Santoro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/24644/raffaele-santoro) is not in the layout that I wish (The key is supposed to take the same layout as the one in the picture that I wish to reproduce). I would greatly appreciate all forms of help in solving this one remaining problem. Below is the updated MWE thanks to @[Raffaele Santoro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/24644/raffaele-santoro):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
    patterns,positioning,
    shadows,shapes,
    trees}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{0081FF}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,
            -,line width=1.5mm,>=stealth',
            level/.style={sibling distance = 3cm/#1, level distance = 10mm},  
            basic/.style = {draw, drop shadow, font=\sffamily\small, text=white,
                rounded corners=2pt, thin}, % <---
            split/.style = {basic, fill=blue},    % <---
            leaf/.style = {basic, fill=#1},      % <---
            leaf/.default = red
            ]
            \node [split,rectangle, draw, fill=black,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1.1cm] {}
            child{ node [split,circle,minimum size=1cm] {}
                child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=.5cm] {}}
                child{ node [split, circle, minimum size=1cm] {}
                    child{ node [split,circle,minimum size=1cm] {} 
                        child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=.5cm] {}}
                        child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=.5cm] {}}}
                    child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=.5cm] {}}
                }
            }
            %
            child{ node [split,circle,minimum size=1cm] {}
                child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=.5cm] {}}
                child{ node [split,circle,minimum size=1cm] {}
                    child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=.5cm] {}}
                    child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=.5cm] {}}
                }
            };
            \fill (-3,-5.5) rectangle(-2,-5.25) (-1.5,-5.5 ) node () {ROOT}; 
            \fill[blue] (-3,-6.5) circle(.4)  (-1.5,-6.5 )node () {Text for blue circle};
            \fill[red] (-3,-7.5) circle(.2)  (-2,-7.5) node () {Text for red circle};
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Tree Structure}
        \label{fig:decision-tree}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Below is the output from the updated MWE:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `forest`.

```
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701184/
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{%
  broot/.style={rounded corners,fill=black,text width=25pt,text height=7.5pt},
  binode/.style={circle,inner sep=5pt,fill=blue},
  rleaf/.style={circle,inner sep=2.5pt,fill=red!50!black},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{forest}
    for descendants={%
      if n children=0{rleaf}{binode},
      s sep'+=25pt,
    },
    broot,
    [[[][[[][]][]]][[][[][]]]]
    \node (kroot) [broot, anchor=west,below=10pt of !r121 |- current bounding box.south]  {};
    \node (kinode) [binode, anchor=center] at (kroot.center -| !r22) {};
    \node (kleaf) [rleaf, anchor=north,below=5pt of kroot.south]  {};
    \foreach \i/\j in {kroot.east/root,kinode.east/internal node,kleaf.center -| kroot.east/terminal or leaf node} \node [font=\sffamily,anchor=west] at (\i) {\j};
  \end{forest}
  
  \caption{Tree structure}\label{fig:tree-structure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: tree structure diagram with key]

### EDIT

I don't know quite how spread out you want the tree, given that the original target picture isn't very spaced out, so the following is designed to be flexible.

- increase `s sep` for horizontal spread
- increase `l sep` for vertical spread
- use `fit=rectangle` **or** `fit=band` to increase horizontal spread
- use `edge+={<tikz options>}` to style the edges

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{%
  broot/.style={rounded corners,fill=black,text width=25pt,text height=7.5pt},
  binode/.style={circle,inner sep=5pt,fill=blue},
  rleaf/.style={circle,inner sep=2.5pt,fill=red!50!black},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{forest}
    for descendants={% increase s sep for horizontal spread
      if n children=0{rleaf}{binode},
      s sep'+=50pt,
      edge+={ultra thick},
    },
    broot,
    for tree={% uncomment one of the fit lines if desired; increase l sep to increase vertical spread
      l sep'+=25pt,
%       fit=band,
      fit=rectangle,
    },
    [[[][[[][]][]]][[][[][]]]]
    \node (kroot) [broot, anchor=east,below=20pt of !r1211 |- current bounding box.south]  {};
    \node (kinode) [binode, anchor=center] at (kroot.center -| !r122) {};
    \node (kleaf) [rleaf, anchor=north,below=10pt of kroot.south]  {};
    \foreach \i/\j in {kroot.east/root,kinode.east/internal node,kleaf.center -| kroot.east/terminal or leaf node} \node [font=\sffamily,anchor=west] at (\i) {\j};
  \end{forest}
  
  \caption{Tree structure}\label{fig:tree-structure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: spacier tree with spacier key]

### EDIT 2

I originally thought to use `matrix of nodes` to make the key. However, this doesn't work out-of-the-box in a `forest` environment. I suspect this is because `forest` alters the catcodes. Anyway, after fiddling a bit, I got this to work by simply using the `ampersand replacement` option and thought I'd post the result as an alternative.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\tikzset{%
  broot/.style={rounded corners,fill=black,text width=25pt,text height=7.5pt},
  binode/.style={circle,inner sep=5pt,fill=blue},
  rleaf/.style={circle,inner sep=2.5pt,fill=red!50!black},
}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{forest}
    /tikz/ampersand replacement=\&,
    for descendants={% increase s sep for horizontal spread
      if n children=0{rleaf}{binode},
      s sep'+=50pt,
      edge+={ultra thick},
    },
    broot,
    for tree={% uncomment one of the fit lines if desired; increase l sep to increase vertical spread
      l sep'+=25pt,
%       fit=band,
      fit=rectangle,
    },
    [[[][[[][]][]]][[][[][]]]]
    \matrix [matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,column 1/.style={anchor=center},column 2/.style={anchor=west},column 3/.style={anchor=center},column 4/.style={anchor=west},nodes={font=\sffamily},below=10pt of current bounding box.south]  {%
        |[broot]|{} \& root \& |[binode]|{} \& internal node\\
        |[rleaf]|{} \& terminal or leaf node \& \& \\
      };
  \end{forest}

  \caption{Tree structure}\label{fig:tree-structure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: spacier tree with matrix of nodes for key]

Irritatingly, the alignment in the key still doesn't look quite right to me ....

Comment: If anybody knows why `binode` doesn't align quite how I expect (!), please let me know.

Comment: Thanks @cfr. I have 2 questions:
1. How do I increase the thickness of the connecting lines (branches)?
2. How do I magnify the diagram so that it becomes less huddled?

Comment: @itc Please see edit.

Comment: Well explained @cfr. With the above explanation, I made the perfect adjustments I wanted. Many thanks.

Comment: @itc See second edit if you're interested in using a `matrix of nodes` for the key. I tried to do this earlier, but it didn't work out-of-the-box inside `forest`. However, the solution turns out to be extremely straightforward, so I'm posting it as an alternative.

Comment: Many thanks @cfr

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
    patterns,positioning,
    shadows,shapes,
    trees}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{0081FF}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,
            ->,>=stealth',
            level/.style={sibling distance = 3cm/#1, level distance = 10mm},  
            basic/.style = {draw, drop shadow, font=\sffamily\small, text=white,
                rounded corners=2pt, thin}, % <---
            split/.style = {basic, fill=blue},    % <---
            leaf/.style = {basic, fill=#1},      % <---
            leaf/.default = red
            ]
            \node[white] [split,rectangle, draw, fill=black,minimum size=2cm] {\Large \bfseries Long text indide}
            child{ node [split,circle,minimum size=2cm] {}
                child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=1cm] {}}
                child{ node [split, circle, minimum size=2cm] {}
                    child{ node [split,circle,minimum size=2cm] {} 
                        child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=1cm] {}}
                        child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=1cm] {}}}
                    child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=1cm] {}}
                }
            }
            %
            child{ node [split,circle,minimum size=2cm] {}
                child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=1cm] {}}
                child{ node [split,circle,minimum size=2cm] {}
                    child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=1cm] {}}
                    child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=1cm] {}}
                }
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Tree Structure}
        \label{fig:decision-tree}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**ADD**: Its the better I can have for You:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
    patterns,positioning,
    shadows,shapes,
    trees}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{0081FF}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,
            ->,>=stealth',
            level/.style={sibling distance = 3cm/#1, level distance = 10mm},  
            basic/.style = {draw, drop shadow, font=\sffamily\small, text=white,
                rounded corners=2pt, thin}, % <---
            split/.style = {basic, fill=blue},    % <---
            leaf/.style = {basic, fill=#1},      % <---
            leaf/.default = red
            ]
            \node [split,rectangle, draw, fill=black] {\Huge \textcolor{black}{long text}}
            child{ node [split,circle,minimum size=2cm] {}
                child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=1cm] {}}
                child{ node [split, circle, minimum size=2cm] {}
                    child{ node [split,circle,minimum size=2cm] {} 
                        child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=1cm] {}}
                        child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=1cm] {}}}
                    child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=1cm] {}}
                }
            }
            %
            child{ node [split,circle,minimum size=2cm] {}
                child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=1cm] {}}
                child{ node [split,circle,minimum size=2cm] {}
                    child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=1cm] {}}
                    child{ node [leaf,circle,minimum size=1cm] {}}
                }
            };
            \fill (-3,-5.5) rectangle(-2,-5.25) (-1.5,-5.5 ) node () {ROOT}; 
            \fill[blue] (-3,-6.5) circle(.4)  (-1.5,-6.5 )node () {Text for blue circle};
            \fill[red] (-3,-7.5) circle(.2)  (-2,-7.5) node () {Text for red circle};
        
        \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Tree Structure}
        \label{fig:decision-tree}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Raffaele Santoro. Problem number 3 has been solved now. However I am still experiencing problems 1 and 2. You have managed to make the root of my decision diagram rectangular in shape by using **some text**. However the root of my decision tree is supposed to be a black rectangle **without any text**. Also, I would gladly appreciate to have a **key** to the tree diagram as shown in the picture that I wish to reproduce. Once again thank you.

Comment: @itc See my update.

Comment: Thank you very much @Raffaele Santoro. Problems 2 and 3 have been solved now. However Problem 1 still stands. Can you kindly assist with making the adjustments to the key so that it is properly aligned and also it takes the same layout as the diagram that I wish to reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly of topic (sorry, your question is not entirely clear to me, your MWE to me looks fine) ... so some effort is put in writing a  shorter code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                positioning,
                shadows}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{0081FF}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \tikzset{      > = stealth',
            basic/.style = {draw, thin, fill=#1, inner sep=0pt,
                            font=\sffamily\small, text=white,
                            drop shadow}, 
              root/.style = {basic=black, rounded corners, minimum height=6mm, minimum width=12mm},
             split/.style = {basic=blue, circle, minimum size=8mm},
              leaf/.style = {basic=red, circle, minimum size=2mm},
               lbl/.style = {scale=0.6, below right = of #1, align=left, text=black}
                    }
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, % or whatever magnification factor you wish
                level/.style={sibling distance = 3cm/#1, level distance = 10mm},
                 ]
            \node [root] {}
                child{ node [split] {} 
                    child{ node (L) [leaf, name=L] {}}
                    child{ node [split] {} 
                            child{ node [split] {}
                                child{ node (B) [leaf] {}}
                                child{ node [leaf] {}}                               
                                }
                            child{ node [leaf] {}}
                        }
                    }
                child{ node [split] {}
                        child{ node [leaf] {}}
                        child{ node [split] {}
                                child{ node [leaf] {}}
                                child{ node [leaf] {}}
                            }
                    };
             \end{tikzpicture}\\[2ex]
             
        \begin{tabular}{rl}
                \tikz[baseline=-3pt]\node[scale=0.6, root] {}; & root   \\[3pt]
                \tikz[baseline=-3pt]\node[scale=0.6, split]{}; & split  \\[3pt]
                \tikz[baseline=-3pt]\node[leaf] {};            & leaf
        \end{tabular}\hfil~

        \caption{Tree Structure}
        \label{fig:decision-tree}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, to my taste looks nicer, if legends are right of tree:

[image]

For this design are needed minor changes (marked by `<---` to previous MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                positioning,
                shadows}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{0081FF}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \tikzset{      > = stealth',
            basic/.style = {draw, thin, fill=#1, inner sep=0pt,
                            font=\sffamily\small, text=white,
                            drop shadow}, 
              root/.style = {basic=black, rounded corners, minimum height=6mm, minimum width=12mm},
             split/.style = {basic=blue, circle, minimum size=8mm},
              leaf/.style = {basic=red, circle, minimum size=2mm},
               lbl/.style = {scale=0.6, below right = of #1, align=left, text=black}
                    }
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,
                baseline=(current bounding box.center),
                level/.style={sibling distance = 3cm/#1, level distance = 10mm},
                 ]
            \node [root] {}
                child{ node [split] {} 
                    child{ node (L) [leaf, name=L] {}}
                    child{ node [split] {} 
                            child{ node [split] {}
                                child{ node (B) [leaf] {}}
                                child{ node [leaf] {}}                               
                                }
                            child{ node [leaf] {}}
                        }
                    }
                child{ node [split] {}
                        child{ node [leaf] {}}
                        child{ node [split] {}
                                child{ node [leaf] {}}
                                child{ node [leaf] {}}
                            }
                    };
             \end{tikzpicture}
        \qquad
        \begin{tabular}{rl}
                \tikz[baseline=-3pt]\node[scale=0.6, root] {}; & root   \\[3pt]
                \tikz[baseline=-3pt]\node[scale=0.6, split]{}; & split  \\[3pt]
                \tikz[baseline=-3pt]\node[leaf] {};            & leaf
        \end{tabular}\hfil~

        \caption{Tree Structure}
        \label{fig:decision-tree}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Your diagram can be magnified by scaling of `tikzpicture` (as done now) or better with changing distances between nodes and their sizes.

Comment: `[[[][[[][]][]]][[][[][]]]]` is even shorter ;).

Comment: @cfr, of course. I prepare such solution for addendum to answer, but you bit me for some minutes :-( - +1 for your answer.

Comment: Sorry :(. Your answer appeared while I was writing mine, but it wasn't `forest`. (Already +1 both existing answers, which are probably more what the OP wants.)

Comment: @cfr, no problem.I'm glad that you wrote answer! BTW, temporary I use small ancient laptop (mine PC with two screens is on service), where I have difficulties to keep on screen visible two solutions ...  hopefully situation will improve soon :-). It seems that I'm a bit spoiled with use of two screens ...

Comment: My machine is a laptop with a 12.5" screen. The possibility of keeping two solutions on screen hadn't occurred to me ;).